# How to pass checkbox id to the modal box?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to checkbox id to the modal box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805540/how-to-checkbox-id-to-the-modal-box)

I have a table which each row have a checkbox and a button.  whenever the button is pressed, a modal box will appear and at the same time the checkbox will get checked as well.

The modal box will as ask user if want to delete particular record. If Yes, the form will be submitted.  If No, the checkbox will be unchecked.

I am facing issue with getting the checkbox unchecked.  Anyone can assist with sample code?  How do I pass the checkbox id to the modal box so that that particular checkbox can be unchecked?

thank you.

```
         var buttons3 = $("#yns button").click(function(e) { 
        // get user input
         var yes = buttons3.index(this) === 0;
         if (yes){
         $('form#form1').submit();
         return true;
         } 
        else{
         //How to get the particular Checkbox id so that it can be unchecked? 

$(this).dialog("close");

     return false;

     } 

    });
```

Comment: can you post some relevant code

Comment: var buttons3 = $("#yns button").click(function(e) {
 
        // get user input
        var yes = buttons3.index(this) === 0;
        
        if (yes){
         $('form#form1').submit();
         return true;
        }
        else{
               //How to get the particular Checkbox id so that it can be unchecked?   
         $(this).dialog("close");
         return false;
        }
    });

Comment: <div class="widget modal2" id="yns">
        <header><h2>Confirmation</h2></header>
        <section>
            <p>
                Do you want to delete this item?
            </p>

            <!-- yes/no buttons -->

            <p>
                <button class="button" type="button">Yes</button>
                <button class="button" type="button">No</button>
            </p>
        </section>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

get the id of check box when clicking the button

```
var id =     $(this).parents('td').siblings()find('.checkbox').attr('id')
```

uncheck the check box

```
$('#'+id).attr("checked", false)
```

with out  knowing much details . this may not be the exact answer.........

Comment: What is 'td' you stated over here?

Comment: parents('td') is referring to ???

Comment: i thought your check box and button is in two td s in a row

Comment: please provide your html . i said it before

Comment: <tr>                                        
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="measure<?php echo $count;?>
    " name="measureid[]" value="<?php echo $items>"></td>
    <td><?php  echo $Name;?></td>
    <td>
  <ul id="tip" class="abuttons">
    <li><a class="button"><span class="edit" title="Edit"></span></a></li>
    <li><a rel="#yns" id="unitbtn<?php echo $count;?>" class="modalInput button">
       <span class="delete" title="Delete"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>

Answer (score 0):

you can assign it to a global variable and access from model dialog cancel event. In onchange event of the checkbox assign the checkbox id to a global variable. And in cancel event of the model dialog you can access it again.

```
var chk;


$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").click(function(event) {
      chk=  event.target.id;
    });
```

Comment: How do I assign it to a global variable? pls assist.

Comment: see i have added code to assign it to a global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can find the checkbox by using its common root with the button, then store that object into a variable so that the scope is accessible by the code that reacts to the Cancel operation. I think you could easily use a closure from the Click handler, but here is the code for using the `window` object as a placeholder.

**jQuery > 1.6+**

```
$('#table .button').click(function(){
    //alter this selector to find the checkbox associated with the button.
    window.my_checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']",$(this).parent()).attr('checked','checked');

    //load modal box...

    if(cancel)
        window.my_checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
});
```

**jQuery < 1.5**

```
$('#table .button').click(function(){
    //alter this selector to find the checkbox associated with the button.
    window.my_checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']",$(this).parent()).prop('checked',true);

    //load modal box...

    if(cancel)
        window.my_checkbox.prop('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    <tr>                                        
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="measure<?php echo $count;?>" name="measureid[]" value="<?php echo $items>"></td>
                                        <td><?php  echo $Name;?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <ul id="tip" class="abuttons">
                                                <li><a class="button"><span class="edit" title="Edit"></span></a></li>
                                                <li><a rel="#yns" id="unitbtn<?php echo $count;?>" class="modalInput button"><span class="delete" title="Delete"></span></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```