# How to checkbox id to the modal box?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass checkbox id to the modal box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805127/how-to-pass-checkbox-id-to-the-modal-box)

I have a table which each row have a checkbox and a button. whenever the button is pressed, a modal box will appear and at the same time the checkbox will get checked as well.

The modal box will as ask user if want to delete particular record. If Yes, the form will be submitted. If No, the checkbox will be unchecked.

I am facing issue with getting the checkbox unchecked. Anyone can assist with sample code? How do I pass the checkbox id to the modal box so that that particular checkbox can be unchecked?

Thank you.

```
     var buttons3 = $("#yns button").click(function(e) { 
    // get user input
     var yes = buttons3.index(this) === 0;
     if (yes){
     $('form#form1').submit();
     return true;
     } 
    else{
     //How to get the particular Checkbox id so that it can be unchecked? 

  $(this).dialog("close");

 return false;

 } 

});
```

My Modal Box Html:

```
<div class="widget modal2" id="yns"> <header>
 <h2>Confirmation</h2></header> <section>
   <p> Do you want to delete this item? </p> <!-- yes/no buttons --> <p> 
<button class="button" type="button">Yes</button> 
<button class="button" type="button">No</button> 
</p> </section> </div>
```

My Table HTML:

```
<tr>                                        
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="measure<?php echo $count;?>
    " name="measureid[]" value="<?php echo $items>"></td>
    <td><?php  echo $Name;?></td>
    <td>
  <ul id="tip" class="abuttons">
    <li><a class="button"><span class="edit" title="Edit"></span></a></li>
    <li><a rel="#yns" id="unitbtn<?php echo $count;?>" class="modalInput button">
       <span class="delete" title="Delete"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Modal and Table within same php page.

Comment: My Table HTML:
 <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" id="measure<?php echo $count;?>" name="measureid[]" value="<?php echo $items>"></td>
 <td><?php  echo $Name;?></td>
 <td><ul id="tip" class="abuttons">
      <li><a class="button"><span class="edit" title="Edit"></span></a></li>
   <li><a rel="#yns" id="unitbtn<?php echo $count;?>" class="modalInput button"><span class="delete" title="Delete"></span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

Comment: My Modal box HTML:
 
<div class="widget modal2" id="yns"> <header><h2>Confirmation</h2></header> <section> <p> Do you want to delete this item? </p> <!-- yes/no buttons --> <p> <button class="button" type="button">Yes</button> <button class="button" type="button">No</button> </p> </section> </div>

Comment: Modal Box HTML and Table HTML are on the same page.

Comment: deja vu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805127/how-to-pass-checkbox-id-to-the-modal-box

Comment: either its you asking the same question with a different account or its coincidence ...

Comment: Hi 3nigma, any idea how to be done? Coz I have tried as indicated on earlier thread but no avail.

Comment: @BlurKing people have starting voting to close the quesitons, we can maybe close one as a duplicate of another? Did you find an answer in the other duplicate?

Comment: No I did not.  I am sorry for the confusion. Please close the other.

Comment: You want *this* one open and the OTHER one closed right? Voted to close that one as exact duplicate of _this_ one.

Comment: Anyone know how to deal with such situation? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May-be an easy way to do that is to uncheck every checkboxes in your table if the user clicks on No.

Comment: But that is not the intended interaction between user and the program.

Answer (score 0):

your question not clear to me, so i have assumed (not a very good one) that only one checkbox is checked at a moment so you can uncheck it by

```
$("input[name='measureid\\[\\]']:checked").removeAttr("checked")
```

it will uncheck the checkbox that is checked and has `name="measureid[]"`

Comment: It is a table controlled by a loop in php.  There will be more than 1 row. I am just putting in how a typically row will look like in my code.  From your answer, if I have 100 rows, then I have to have 100 statements you provided above.  How can i pass that parameters to my script?

Comment: no you dont need to put 100 statements for 100 rows just put this statement in the else part of your code just before `$(this).dialog("close");`

Comment: see here how it will work hopefully you will get the ideAa http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/msRqv/

Comment: I am aware of this. However, that means all the checkboxes will be unchecked.  However, I only want the same row checkbox to be unchecked.